# Unable to sudo apt-get install python3-venv or python-venv

Tags: python, ubuntu, sudo, apt-get, python-venv

I am able to run py commands on my gitbash but since im trying to do a task(reading memory dump through UART) that is using Ubuntu OS, i thought of using the Ubuntu terminal instead since most discussions online are using Ubuntu terminals. I tried python3 -m venv and also python -m venv but no it prompts me to sudo apt-get install python3 instead...i also tried sudo apt-get install python,no avail. Any idea why? I am very new at this.attached is the snap shot of my terminal.[image]

Comment: I think `venv` is sometimes included with python with no extra installation necessary. Have you tried just using it?

Comment: Yes, i tried python -m venv and python3 -m venv but it prompts to install python3

Comment: You don't have python3? What happens if you try running just `python3`? Maybe you need to install that.